# Why is my KendoUI Chart changing the date format in a javascript variable it's not even connected to? And how to make it stop?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm pulling a bunch of entries from a database, storing them in a variable, and then filtering them down to a separate variable based on various criteria. Once my Kendo Chart is initialized, based on the filtered version, it somehow changes the date format of the entries in the first variable, but my code expects them to be in the original format. I've tracked the problem down to a single line, but I need that line.

I'm using C# in ASP.NET MVC4.

Here's the ajax call that gets the data:

```
$.ajax({
    // gets request logs
    url: 'Usage/GetLogs',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        window.logs = data;
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error in GetLogs: ' + status);
    }
});
```

This performs fine, and the `logs` array contains around 2000 Json objects, each of which look something like this:

```
CalcId: 129
Date: "/Date(1373432400000)/"
DateTime: "/Date(1373432621070)/"
Id: 1
ProvId: 2
```

Then the following function is called, with `firstfilter = true`:

```
function FilterLogs(firstfilter) {
    window.currentlogs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(logs[i].Date.substring(6)) >= Date.parse(StartDate)
         && parseInt(logs[i].Date.substring(6)) <= Date.parse(EndDate)
         && $('#ProvCheckBox' + logs[i].ProvId).hasClass('visible')
         && $('#ProvCheckBox' + logs[i].ProvId).prop('checked')
         && $('#CalcCheckBox' + logs[i].CalcId).prop('checked'))
            currentlogs.push(logs[i]);
    }
    if (firstfilter)
        InitializeOutput();
    else
        UpdateOutput();
}
```

This works fine, the first time it is called. `parseInt(logs[i].Date.substring(6))` pulls the number out of the `Date` property, and the comparison works. Every log within the specified date range and whose Calc and Prov checkboxes are checked is pushed into `currentlogs`. Then `InitializeOutput` is called:

```
function InitializeOutput() {
    $('#DateChart').kendoChart({
        dataSource: {
            data: currentlogs,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "number" },
                        //Date: { type: "date" }
                        //This is the problematic line of code
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            aggregate: "count",
            field: "Id",
            categoryField: "Date"
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            baseUnit: "months",
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If `Date: { type: "date" }` is uncommented, the next time `FilterLogs` is called, the `Date` property has been changed in each of the Json objects contained in `logs`. They now look like this:

```
CalcId: 129
Date: Wed Jul 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
DateTime: "/Date(1373432621070)/"
Id: 1
ProvId: 2
```

As soon as it hits the `if (parseInt(logs[i].Date.substring(6))` statement, I get the following: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'substring'.

But I need that line of code uncommented, because without it, I can't get `baseUnit` to do anything other than `"days"`. Specifying `"weeks"` or `"months"` or `"years"` gets ignored, and the chart displays days.

I've tried changing all instances of `currentlogs` to a local variable `templogs`, and then copying `templogs` into `currentlogs` once the filtering is done, and I've also called `InitializeOutput` after `FilterLogs` completes, instead of from inside it, so that 'templogs' shouldn't even exist by the time the Chart is created, and I get the same result.

Interestingly, if I change the starting values of the (not shown) kendo DatePickers so that there are no logs inside the date range, and `currentlogs` stays empty on the first `FilterLogs` call, and then I open up the date range, I don't get any problems. But I don't think `push` is the problem because I've stepped through the code and `logs` stays normal after `push` is executed.

What is going on?

I'd like to keep handling the dates in the way that I do because everything else in the code works just fine the way they are. Why is kendo screwing with `logs` when it's only hooked up to `currentlogs`?

Comment: You say that you get the error as soon as you hit "if (firstfilter)". This if statement alone will not cause an exception; are you sure that the exception is not being raised by "UpdateOutput();" (please include the source for this)? Is firstfilter still true on the second pass?

Comment: No, the exception is in "if (parseInt(logs[i].Date.substring(6))" (edited), it can't take a substring because logs[i].Date is no longer a string. firstfilter is undefined on the second pass but the error gets thrown before it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I fixed it. I think `currentlogs.push(logs[i])` was pushing a reference to the json object, instead of making a copy of it. Changed it to:

```
currentlogs.push({
    Date: logs[i].Date,
    DateTime: logs[i].DateTime,
    ProvId: logs[i].ProvId,
    CalcId: logs[i].CalcId
});
```

and it works now.